# "Цветное" условие в Excel

Tags: excel

Скажите, возможно ли в Excel применить для выбранных ячеек условие
`ЕСЛИ(a>b; ЯЧЕЙКА КРАСНАЯ; ЯЧЕЙКА ЗЕЛЕНАЯ)` ?

Answer (score 6):

можно так.

> `Выделить диапазон -> закладка
> «Главная» -> «Условное
> форматирование»`

и выбрать что нужно. вот и все.

Answer (score 2):

Условное форматирование "понимает" условия, поэтому в формуле функция не обязательна:

*=a>b*

*=a<=b*

Возможно, второе условие лишнее: изначально залить ячейку зеленым.

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. Самый простой. Использовать условное форматирование.
2. Извращенный. Написать свою функцию

   ```
   Sub fColor(cell As Range, b As Integer) 
       ' Для примера первые десять строк и столбцов. 
       'i- номер строки 
       'j- Номер столбца 
       For i = 1 To 10 
           For j = 1 To 10 
               If Cells(i, j) > b Then 
                   Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 255 'красный
               Else 
                   Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 5296274 'оттенок зеленого
               End If 
           Next j 
       Next i 
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: 1. Условное форматирование / Использовать формулу для определения форматируемых ячеек: (Пишешь формулу, указываешь диапазон и формат.)

Comment: Я дал направление, а не решение.

Comment: На свое усмотрение. Там был вариант со своей функцией. Никто не отметил как полезное, поэтому и удалил.

Comment: Совершенно верно, это VBA.

Comment: `' abc` — это комментарий так выглядит в VBA?

Comment: Да, так выглядит комментарий.